# How to print multiple copies of a file using win32com (or an alternative)

Tags: python, printing, win32com

I'm trying to send multiple copies of a file to a printer using the win32com library. Printing a single copy works fine, but it appears the Copies parameter doesn't affect the number of copies printed (even if I put Copies=2, as below, it only ever prints out a single page).

```
from win32com import client

word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

word.Documents.Open(file_to_print)
word.ActivePrinter = printer
word.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(Copies=2)

word.ActiveDocument.Close()
word.Quit()
```

If this additional information helps, I am using Python 3.4 and Word 2013.

If there is a superior way to just open and then print a .docx file from python that would also be a wonderful answer. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies, but actually the 'Copies=2' doesn't even work: it only prints one copy (I just edited my language to hopefully reflect this), which is the source of my problem! Thank you.

Comment: I've had the exact same problem, it seems the win32com module doesn't take those parameters into account. You could simply execute it twice if 2 copies is all you want, but for other parameters like `PrintZoomColumn` it would prove a problem.