# Printing multiple copies of a Word Document using win32com

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, win32com

I am attempting to create a `tkinter` interface that will allow me to print multiple copies of a Word Document. For this  am using `win32com`.

```
from win32com import client
from tkinter import *
import time
import os

def printWordDocument(filename,NumPage1):
    word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

    path=str(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    path = path[:-16]
    filename=path+filename

    word.Documents.Open(filename)
    word.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(Copies=2,Collate=True)
    root.focus()
    time.sleep(10)
    word.ActiveDocument.Close()

    word.Quit()

root=Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
Button(root,text='Print',command=lambda:printWordDocument('PrintThis.docx',2)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I press the button to print the Document, it only prints a single copy, it is ignoring the 'Copies' option given to it.

Does anyone know why it is doing this?

P.S. I have looked at other question that have been posted and either they aren't the same issue as mine or there isn't an answer.

Comment: The indentation of the code in your question needs to corrected.

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7994155/355230) it looks like you're not passing arguments in the `word.ActiveDocument.PrintOut()` call correctly (it doesn't have keyword arguments like `Copies=`, and `Collate=`).

Comment: I fixed the indentation (an error in copying the text) and checked out that other answer, but I don't see a difference in how they're told to write and how I have written it.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.printout(v=office.14).aspx) it is indeed option.

Comment: @Veitch: Sorry, my mistake, your calling sequence is fine. I don't know what the problem is (see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951496/how-to-print-multiple-copies-of-a-file-using-win32com-or-an-alternative)). Perhaps it's some kind of win32com bug. At any rate, the workaround for this particular problem seems like it would be to simply execute the `PrintOut` method multiple times corresponding to the number of copies you want.